# Asset pipelining for individual view with fingerprinting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails 4.0 with ruby 2.0.
And i've 100's of js and css files. 
I dont want them to load on all pages.
So i removed require_tree in application.js and application.css
I include the required css and js using

```
<% javascript_include_tag "js_file" %>
<% stylesheet_include_tag "css_file" %>
```

My questions are
1. Do i need to precompile assets?
2. Will they be formed into a single file and sent on client side?
3. What is and how can turbo_link gem help me here?
4. Should i use controller based assets and use their appropriate cs and js file for inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Do I need to precompile assets?**

No, but it entirely depends on your production environment. Services such as Heroku require precompiled assets

**2. Will they be formed into a single file and sent on client side?**

The assets which are required in the application.css will be merged into that file. However, if you have controller-specific css/js, and call them from your layout accordingly, they should be compiled into their respective files

**3. What is and how can turbo_link gem help me here?**

`Turbolinks` is a gem designed to help boost page load times, by cutting down the number of times the  elements have to be loaded. Basically, if you're using the same controller, turbolinks will just replace the  part of your page with an Ajax request

So nope, Turbolinks won't help you with compilation / organization of your assets :)

**4. Should I use controller based assets and use their appropriate cs and js file for inclusion?**

It depends on your application. The first question I would have is.... *why do you have 100's of CSS & JS files?* After you find the answer to this, you can then work on making the system work to the most efficient requirements

Comment: Its a dashboard theme i downloaded, its has a lot of widgets elements etc, so it has a lot of files. If i include them individually in each file. will it be fingerprinted and act efficiently?

Comment: I think it should be Okay. Why don't you just include the folder for the theme, like this: /*= require '/theme' - this should make it work well for you

Comment: but wont it load all the css and js files for each and every page?

Comment: Well, this is why it's important to look at your system. Obviously, you can't show CSS on a page which doesn't call the CSS. This means that if you want all those files to appear on a certain page, we will be able to provision for that page. The asset pipeline is quite flexible if you set it up correctly, which is why you should explain when you'd like the CSS files to load

Comment: example for the login page i don't need to load the bootstrap datepicker js and css. But i'll require some css ans js for tabs. For each view i need only few css and js out of a lot.

Comment: Okay, there are a bunch of options here. The most important thing is to know which elements you want to load on which pages. It sounds like you're looking for some sort of solution to just make it so you can define the different files, and they'll be included; but in order to receive a good answer, you'll have to be a bit more specific I think

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39863/discussion-between-hariharasudhan-and-rich-peck)

Comment: I am available if you want to talk